# Remove the controller name and function in url

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

url::http://localhost/trading/tradingcontroller/index/Titan-Company.html

remove tradingcontroller/index in url...

display url :: http://localhost/trading/Titan-Company.html

please help me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

---

In config/routes.php file, set like this:

---

```
$route['tradingcontroller'] = 'tradingcontroller';
$route['(:any)'] = 'tradingcontroller/index/$1';
```